# verify invocation n times, depending on whether test run in isolation or as part of suite

Tags: java, junit, mockito, verification

when developing I like to run tests in isolation, but obviously when in production the tests get run as part of suite, so in my code I have this :

```
 verify(myService, atLeast(1)).save((MyPojo) any());
 verify(myService, atMost(2)).save((MyPojo) any());
```

is there a better way - I am using Mockito.

My mocks are created via spring and mockito, so a mock instance is shared between the methods of a test class.

Comment: Why do you have that?  Are you somehow sharing a mock between different tests?  I don't think you want to do that.

Comment: @DavidWallace why not ? I have one mock instance for one testclass instance, and the different method test different methods. However, one of the mocks methods are used in two transactions of work. So they get called in two different places as part of larger units of work

Comment: If you have one mock instance for each test class instance, then you are NOT sharing a mock between tests.  JUnit instantiates the test class afresh for each test method.

Comment: @DavidWallace no not in my case, I am using Mockito if it makes any difference. Wille xpand the question

Comment: What do you mean "not in my case"?  That's what JUnit does.  Unless you've declared things as static.

Comment: OK, I read your update.  Why are you using Spring to create your mocks?  Why not just use Mockito?  If you declare them in your class and use Mockito annotations on them, you'll get fresh mocks for each instance of your test class.

Comment: @DavidWallace they are created by mockito via spring... so i cam make use of springs inbuilt mockmvc... and autowire them, without defining a nock for each service class manually.

Comment: OK, but I am concerned that this strategy means that your unit tests are likely to behave differently when run individually than when run en masse.  That's not a good thing for unit tests to do.  Please consider creating your mocks differently, even if you instantiate them individually within a `setUp` method or something similar.

Comment: @DavidWallace yeah but thats the only difference, the one I highlighted in the question. I could refactor everythign, or I could just leave everything with that verification....

Comment: If it's only a single mock that is giving you this issue, why don't you just manually create the one mock?

Answer (score 0):

With Mockito I can simply use the [reset method](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17). Specifically designed for container based injection of mocks.